# How can I split numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

How can I split an array in numpy, why I am getting this error ?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> d= np.array(range(10),np.float32)
>>> b, a = d[:3,:], d[3:,:]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: too many indices for array
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array `d` is one dimensional; however when you do `d[3:,:]` you are specifying two dimensions. Hence the error: `IndexError: too many indices for array`.

Here is the code that gives you the result you are looking for:

```
In [6]: b,a = d[:3], d[3:]

In [7]: b
Out[7]: array([ 0.,  1.,  2.], dtype=float32)

In [8]: a
Out[8]: array([ 3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.], dtype=float32)
```

Another option is:

```
In [4]: b,a = tuple(np.split(d, [3]))
```

Comment: can you explain why ?